# Can Apache Thrift be used on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sockets, thrift

Can I use [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) on Google App Engine?
Since Google App Engine does not support working with sockets what transport can be used?
Is there any transport implementation to use on Google App Engine [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) as transport layer?

PS: Server is supposed to be Java-based (not Python)

Comment: [possible solution](http://moradanen.sopovs.com/2012/07/thrift-exposed-via-webapp-servlet.html)  over http and servlets

Answer (score 1):

Its is very possible to run Thrift on Google App Engine.

Before its was not possible because App engine didn't support socket listening but now its very possible.All u need to do is.

User google [App engine managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/#the_managed_vm_hosting_environment). it allows you to set a custom vm and environment but keep in mind to define a fire wall for your port in order for the thrift server to communicate to the out side world.

See an example [App Engineer socket example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-websocketchat-java). with this all the load is balanced as in App engine according to the number of VMs you have.

Answer (score -1):

There is an ongoing [trusted tester program for sockets](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dF9QR3pnQ2pNa0dqalViSTZoenVkcHc6MQ#gid=0) on App Engine. I'm unaware of any specific effort to try it with Apache Thrift, but I would encourage you to at least sign up and try it, if accepted.

Comment: I've already registered, but did not receive reply. Anyway this is not solution for production yet..